When I click on logout button I still can go back to previous page using browser's back button
I have a servlet where i validate the login using POST and logout using GET. So, i want when i click on logout button, i cannot go back to previous page because the session is terminate. But it did not happen. When i click on logout button i still can go back to previous page.
so here is my code of logout in the servlet
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if ("logout".equals(action)) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.invalidate();
            response.sendRedirect("loginpage.jsp");
        }
    }

logoout button code <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="logout?action=logout">Logout</a></li>
I redirect to the loginpage but when i "click to go back" at the browser, i still can go back even i check the session
here is the code that i put at every single page to validate the session
<%
    HttpSession ses = request.getSession(false);
    if (ses == null || ses.getAttribute("name") == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("login-form.jsp");
        return;
    }
%>


Why did you use get request for logout. Did you redirect to the home page after logout?

The code seems correct. Try disabling browser caches for requests using the back button may use them. For firefox: developer tools -> network -> disable cache.
Or try disabling caches via server response.
If you sent the login via POST, "resending the request for the new session" is excluded. If it doesn't work like that either, try putting the resource inside WEB-INF, this way you can only access via dispatcher from servlet.
